# Averaging unevenly sampled data

Tags: python, numpy, filtering

I have data which consist of the radial distance to the ground, sampled evenly every `d_theta`. I would like to do gaussian smoothing on it, but make the size of the smoothing window a constant in x, rather than be a constant number of points. What is a good way to do this?

I made a function to do it, but it is slow and I haven't even put in the parts that will calculate the edges yet.

If it helps to do it faster, I guess you can assume the floor is flat and use that to calculate how many points to sample, rather than using the actual x-values.

Here is what I have attempted so far:

```
bs = [gaussian(2*n-1,n/2) for n in range (1,500)] #bring the computation of the
bs = [b/b.sum() for b in bs]                      #gaussian outside to speed it up

def uneven_gauss_smoothing(xvals,yvals,sigma):
    newy = []
    for i, xval in enumerate (xvals):

        #find how big the window should be to have the chosen sigma 
        #(or .5*sigma, whatever):
        wheres = np.where(xvals> xval + sigma )[0]
        iright = wheres[0] -i if len(wheres) else 100 
        if i - iright < 0 : 
            newy.append(0)          #not implemented yet
            continue
        if i + iright >= len(xvals):
            newy.append(0)          #not implemented
            continue
        else:
            #weighted average with gaussian curve:
            newy.append((yvals[i-iright:i+iright+1]*bs[iright]).sum())
    return np.array(newy)
```

Sorry it's a bit of a mess--it was so incredibly frustrating to debug that I just ended up using the first solution (usually one which was difficult to read) that came to mind for some of the problems that popped up. But it does work in it's limited way.

Comment: I don't understand what you ar trying to achieve, neither from the description, nor from the code. Could you add a sketch or a more detailed description of what are your measurements, where are the measurement points located, and how exactly would you like to smooth them?

Comment: @Jaime I am scanning the ground with LIDAR, which returns a radial distance for each `d_theta` it makes. Thus portions of the ground closer to the base of the unit are scanned with a smaller dx. I would like to smooth my data by averaging the values in window around a point, and I would like the window to be a constant size in x. This window would include a different amount of data points depending on where it is centered. The ultimate goal is to be able to take the gradient and not have too many theta-dependent effects creep in.

Comment: @Jaime I will try to make my code more readable, I agree that it is not too understandable.

Comment: So you have measurements of the ground height, `z', taken on a rectangular grid of distance from the origin, `r`, and azimuthal angle, `theta`?

Comment: The axis of the measurements (the azimuth I guess) is parallel to the ground, which is `y` in your naming scheme, and `z` in mine. My measurements return one `r` value for each evenly spaced `theta`. I convert this to `xz` coordinates (`xy` in my scheme). Those are the xvals and yvals that are being passed in.

Comment: @Jaime The reason I am trying to do this is that I am trying to do computations involving derivatives, and the same noise in more closely spaced sections gives _much_ larger noise in the first and second derivatives.

Comment: Perhaps I am going about this the wrong way? Another method I had considered using integration after taking the derivative to determine if a given spike was caused by noise (i.e. taking the difference of non-consecutive points).